# Bind, unbind then rebind click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are 4 boxes initially of equal sizes.
When user clicks on any box it enlarges to the big box with content to the height and width of parent `div` and hide other siblings.
On enlarge `div` there are content, close button and continue button to the next `div`. Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
    var $currentBox = false;;
    var open = false;
    var origHeight = $('.box').innerHeight() + 'px';
    var origWidth = $('.box').innerWidth() + 'px';

    $(".clsbtn").click(function(){
        $(".box").animate({
            "height": origHeight,
            "width": origWidth
        },800);

        $(".box").show();
            $(".box-container").show();
            $(".box-content").hide();
            $(".box").on("click");
        });

        $(".box").click(function() {
            if (open) {
                $currentBox = false;
                $(this).animate({
                    "height": origHeight,
                    "width": origWidth
                },800);

                $(".box").show();
                $(".box-container").show();
                $(".box-content").hide();
                open = false;

                $(".box").bind("click");
            } else {
                $currentBox = $(this);
                var width = $('.boxes').innerWidth() + 'px',
                height = $('.boxes').innerHeight() + 'px';
                $(this).animate({
                    "height": height,
                     "width": width
                },800);

                $(this).find(".box-container").hide();
                $(this).find(".box-content").show();

                $(".box").not(this).hide();
                open = true;
                $(".box").unbind("click");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

*Issues:*

1. When box enlarges it disable the clicks on parent `div` (i.e. "box") and the close button working properly. But when on click of close button the rebind function is not working. So if div is close back to its original size then it click is not working to make it enlarge again.
2. Secondly i want to make continue button to next enlarged open div. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide HTML.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wb12zdjq/1/
here is the fiddle but function is not working there its working on my local server, maybe i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of `.bind()` and `.unbind()` I would use `.off()` and `.on()`. Check out [What's the difference between jQuery.bind() and jQuery.on()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9113783/4825796) for more information.

Also any time you unbind or use `off('click')` on an event, you cant just use `bind('click')` or  `on('click')` and expect to get the event back to normal.  You would have to re-declare the event, in your case, the function in the line `$(".box").click(function(){...}`.

```
$(function(){
var $currentBox = false;;
var open = false;
var origHeight = $('.box').innerHeight() + 'px';
var origWidth = $('.box').innerWidth() + 'px';

$(".clsbtn").click(function(){
    $(".box").animate({
        "height": origHeight,
        "width": origWidth
    },800);

    $(".box").show();
        $(".box-container").show();
        $(".box-content").hide();
        $(".box").on("click");
    });

    function activate() {//change here
        if (open) {
            $currentBox = false;
            $(this).animate({
                "height": origHeight,
                "width": origWidth
            },800);

            $(".box").show();
            $(".box-container").show();
            $(".box-content").hide();
            open = false;

            $(".box").on("click",activate());//change here
        } else {
            $currentBox = $(this);
            var width = $('.boxes').innerWidth() + 'px',
            height = $('.boxes').innerHeight() + 'px';
            $(this).animate({
                "height": height,
                 "width": width
            },800);

            $(this).find(".box-container").hide();
            $(this).find(".box-content").show();

            $(".box").not(this).hide();
            open = true;
            $(".box").off("click");//change here
        }
    });

 $(".box").on("click",activate());//change here
});


});
```

Comment: Hi, you miss this thing, the click function can you please review it. Thanks
 $(".box").click(function() {
            if (open) {

Comment: I didnt miss it, i turned it into a function and called it in the 3rd to last line. `$(".box").on("click",activate());`. if you add the jfiddle it will much easier to help you

Comment: sadly its not working and breaks the already functionality the boxes are not enlarging anymore. But thanks for the kind help, Just one question should i put close button before the click function as it only works on enlarge only

Comment: Now i find where the problem is the origHeight and origWidth are giving null in return any idea?